# Find data between two equal value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get data from database if has equal value, this is mySQLi query part of where:

**Query:**

```
car_year BETWEEN '$yearArray[0]' AND '$yearToArray[0]'
```

for example:

```
car_year BETWEEN '2016' AND '2018'
```

**1st Problem:**

It return data from 2016 but until 2017, not 2018.

**2nd Problem:**

If value be like these:

```
car_year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2018'
```

It return nothing, but I want to return all data in this value.

I also tried:

```
car_year >= '$yearArray[0]' AND car_year <= '$yearToArray[0]'
```

But if:

```
car_year >= '2017' AND car_year <= '2017'
```

It return empty but should return data in this value (2017).

Any idea how can I solve these two problems?

---

**Update:**

```
if ($year && $yearTo) {

  $cleanYearTo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $yearTo);
  $yearToArray = explode(",", $cleanYearTo);

  $cleanYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $year);
  $yearArray = explode(",", $cleanYear);

  $sqli = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE car_year BETWEEN '$yearArray[0]' AND '$yearToArray[0]'";

// rest of code
}
```

Sample URL:

> mywebsite.com/index.php?y=1397,2018&yt=1397,2018

This return nothing.

Comment: which data type is car_year?  .. and add  a proper data sample

Comment: @scaisEdge VARCHAR, is it matter?

Comment: @scaisEdge but sorry, what do you mean of proper  data sample?

Comment: show the data you are using for test  .and the query you are using  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge is it enough?

Comment: We don't know what data is in the table, so we have no idea whether it should return anything or not. That's what scaisEdge meant by "data you're using for the test". The PHP is largely irrelevant, only the actual SQL statement used and the table data matters (unless it turns out that simply PHP is generating the statement incorrectly, of course. But if we could see the table data we could prove that more easily)

Comment: We **really** need to see some sample data for (at a minimum) car_year to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem obviously clear, people on comments may be confused due you didn't write what data on your database, but they right, your problem is your data type, you data has `comma` in database like `1397,2018` right? so you are trying to find `2018` in `1397,2018`, think twice! it is impossible, unless use `LIKE` operator like `%2018%` so at least your query should be like this:

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE car_year BETWEEN '$yearArray[0].",".$yearArray[1]' AND '$yearToArray[0].",".$yearToArray[1]'";
```

In other hand, you need to find year by both value, `1397,2018` not only `2018` unless use `LIKE` operator.  Also you can do this without `explode`:

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE car_year BETWEEN '$cleanYear' AND '$cleanYearTo'";
```

But recommend to use:

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE car_year LIKE '%$cleanYear%' AND car_year LIKE '$cleanYearTo'";
```